# Possible Parse bug in matchesKeyInQuery

Tags: parse-platform, constraints, parse-cloud-code, pfquery

If a post in my Parse database is liked, I want to send a push to the author via cloud code.
To be able to send pushes to specific users, all installations store the `objectId` of the current user. To find the author of the liked post, I use the query

```
var userWhosePostWasLikedQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
userWhosePostWasLikedQuery.equalTo(kClassInstallationKeyCurrentUserId, userWhosePostWasLiked.id);
```

This works fine: A single push is sent to the author.

Now I want to send this push only if the author has such pushes enabled. Thus each user stores a push settings array with enable flags for different pushes.
I use now another query for all users who have such pushes enabled:

```
const User = Parse.Object.extend(kClassUser);
var pushEnabledUserQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
pushEnabledUserQuery.equalTo(kClassUserKeyPushSettings, kPushNotificationTypePostLiked);
```

This query correctly returns all users who have such pushes enabled.

Eventually, I want to constrain the query for installations with the author as current user, by this query for users who have pushes enabled. This is done in the following way:

```
var userWhosePostWasLikedQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
userWhosePostWasLikedQuery.equalTo(kClassInstallationKeyCurrentUserId, userWhosePostWasLiked.id);
userWhosePostWasLikedQuery.matchesKeyInQuery(kClassInstallationKeyCurrentUserId, kPFObjectId, pushEnabledUserQuery);
```

Since the old query without the 3rd line returns 1 user, the new query with the additional constraint (`matchesKeyInQuery`) should return the same user, since the author has pushes enabled.
But **it returns 2 users**, the author and another user who liked the post.

To my understanding, this looks like a Parse bug, since all constraints to a query are ANDed.
Any ideas, maybe for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

your var "kPFObjectId" should be change to "user".
the default parse Installation come with the pointer named "user" and not "kPFObjectId". 
I can tell you that Im using the same method ("matchesKeyInQuery") and it is working well:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushForChat", function(request, response) {
    var userId = request.params.userId;
    var groupId = request.params.groupId;

    var query = new Parse.Query('RecentActivity');
    query.equalTo('groupId',groupId);
    query.include('user');
    query.notEqualTo('user',  {__type: "Pointer", className: "_User", objectId: userId});

    var queryInstallation = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    queryInstallation.matchesKeyInQuery('user', 'user', query);

    var message = request.params.messageContent;
    Parse.Push.send({
        where: queryInstallation,
        data: {
            alert: message,
            badge: "Increment",
            title: "מה נשמע?"
        }
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log("Push for chat was successful");
            response.success('Push for chat was successful');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error(error);
            response.error('error');
        },
        useMasterKey:true,
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my problem is that my `pushEnabledUserQuery` returns **only 1 user**, whereas `matchesKeyInQuery(…, …, pushEnabledUserQuery)` returns **2 users**. And this is, to my understanding, impossible since `matchesKeyInQuery` should filter the results of the 1st query, and not return more results.

Comment: no problem, so as i said this function (matchesKeyInQuery) works well for me so probably you have other mistake in your code. i would not think there is a bug in this function if it works for many other ppl. but you know everything can happend :)